# php problem with convert string with comma to int

Tags: php, type-conversion

I have a problem with convert string with comma to int. Look at the example below.

I need int because later i do mathematical operations uses that number.

How I can correctly convert to int in that case?

```
    $value = '10348,8';
    $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    $value = (float)$value;
    $value = $value * 100;
    var_dump($value); // float 1034880
    $value = (int)$value;
    var_dump($value); // int 1034879
```

Comment: I don't understand what a value you would get ?

Comment: You're running into a floating point precision problem. Just use `$value = (int)round($value);`

Comment: $value = '10348,8';
    $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    $value = (float)$value;
    $value = $value * 100;
    var_dump($value); // float 1034880
    $value = (int)round($value);
    var_dump($value); // int 1034879

Comment: @Igor Yuo can avoid converting to float - just split by a comma, get or expandthe second element to 2 digits and convert to int

Comment: Don't use $value = (int)round($value); because, for .5> numbers (ex. 10348.4) it will fail.
Best ways is don't use (int) anyhow, use +0 instead...like $value=$value+0; instead of $value=(int)$value; or $value=(int)round($value);